# Everytime I edit the slightest bit of a Java file, Tomcat restarts automatically. How can I stop it?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, struts

I used to be able to edit my java files and see the differences (system.out.print etc...) but something happened and now everytime I make the smallest change, tomcat restarts and I have to  wait for it to start so I can see the change.

Anyone know why?

Comment: @Ralph yes I am using eclipse

Comment: What is your exact question: Do you want to deploy (small) changes to your tomcat server without restarting it, or do you want to make changes in your code without deploying them automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Context reloadable="false">
```

Does the job.

Thanks abalogh for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your web.xml so that it has the following:

```
<Context reloadable="true">
```

Comment: which web.xml? the one in tomcat/server?

Comment: @user521180: have a look at this article http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-reload (it contains a bit advertising), but it explain the reload stuff very well.

Comment: @Ralph I want to deploy small changes without restarting tomcat

Comment: @user521180: you have a web application I guess, right? then you have a web.xml probably; ctrl-shift-r: web.xml.

Comment: I'm happy I could help :) Can you explain why you haven't accepted my answer but instead created an identical one?

Comment: it's because reloadable must be set to false not true